# AndroidX migration - androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4 or androidx.appcompat:appcompat

Tags: android, androidx

I try to migrate one of the old projects to AndroidX, by using Android Studio/ Refactor/ Migrate to AndroidX...

However, for some of the library projects, when I went through their `build.gradle`, I notice that Android Studio is changing the line from

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

I was expecting the migrated line should be

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

May I know why it is so? I have tried both `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` and `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0`. Both of them compiled and execute well.

But, which is the correct one? The library is using `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`

is included in the `androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0`

You can find info about the library mapping in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings):

```
com.android.support:support-v4   -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4
com.android.support:appcompat-v7 -> androidx.appcompat:appcompat
```

The `androidx.viewpager:viewpager` library is also a [transitive dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-v4/1.0.0) of:

```
androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4 
 -- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui
 -- -- androidx.viewpager:viewpager
```

Comment: But, I'm pretty sure I didn't include `androidx.viewpager:viewpager`. I can find it in either `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4` or `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`

Comment: @CheokYanCheng true, because it is a [transitive dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-v4/1.0.0): `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui -> androidx.viewpager:viewpager`

Comment: Thanks. I click on the link but I have no idea how do you manage to get such hierarchy tree information? As, for consistency, we would like to use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` instead of `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4` across the entire project. But, we are sure it is the right choice. Even though I read through https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418296/72437 , still confusing...

Comment: To navigate: in the bottom of the page there are the *Compile Dependencies* (=transitive or nested dependencies). You can navigate through just clicking the name of the artifact.  About `appcompat`. I am quite sure that you need appcompat (`AppCompatActivity` is there!). If you need the ViewPager you need also other dependencies.  But it is not a problem.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I notice, I can simply replace the 2 lines `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` with 1 line `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'`. Does that still make sense to you?

Comment: Use both. implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0' implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'.